# Telerik RadChart Alternating Background StripLines On ASP Ajax control

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, radchart

I want to show an alternating background colour for the X axis on a line chart on the ASP.Net Ajax RadChart control.

I have found [this article](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radchart-styling-and-appearance-styling-strip-lines.html) that shows the StripLine property for Silverlight and WPF chart control but I cannot find this property on the Ajax control. Maybe I'm just not seeing it  - how can I set the background colour to stripe vertically in  line with the X axis columns?

In the article mentioned the "AlternateStripLineStyle" is located here:
`RadChart1.DefaultView.ChartArea.AxisY.AxisStyles.AlternateStripLineStyle`

However the Ajax control does not have an AxisStyles property.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I think this may be possible using the *MarkedZones* property of the PlotArea but that's not a very elegant solution if indeed it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik themselves [provided the following solution](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/chart/radchart-alternating-background-striplines-on-asp-ajax-control.aspx) which as I suspected uses MarkedZones:

```
public void GenerateStripLines(RadChart chart, int minValue, int maxValue, int step)
{
   for (int i = minValue; i <= maxValue + step; i+=step)
   {
      Color zoneColor;

      if (i % 2 == 0)
         zoneColor = Color.White;
      else
         zoneColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

      var item = new ChartMarkedZone() { ValueStartY = i, ValueEndY = i + step };
      item.Appearance.FillStyle.MainColor = zoneColor;
      chart.PlotArea.MarkedZones.Add(item);
   }           
}
```